# Spring-JSF2 Integration: Target Unreachable, identifier 'customerBean' resolved to null

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, annotations

I'm trying a simple integration of Spring 3 and JSF 2 using annotations only (not using faces-config.xml to define managed beans) and I'm stuck with an error.

The error is:

```java
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /customer/add.xhtml @11,70 value="#{customerBean.firstName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'customerBean' resolved to null
```

This is the page: add.xhtml

```html
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <label>First Name <h:inputText value="#{customerBean.firstName}" /></label><br />
        <label>Last Name <h:inputText value="#{customerBean.lastName}" /></label><br />
        <label>Email <h:inputText value="#{customerBean.email}" /></label><br />
        <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{customerBean.add}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

This is the bean: CustomerBean.java

```
package com.devworkzph.customer.sample.bean;

@Component
@Qualifier("customerBean")
@SessionScoped
public class CustomerBean implements Serializable{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public String add(){
        // code
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

This is a part of my applicationContext.xml

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.devworkzph.customer.sample" />
```

This is a part of my web.xml

```xml
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    classpath:applicationContext.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed CustomerBean.java to have the following annotations:

```java
@Component
@Scope("session")
```

Then added SpringBeanFacesELResolver in faces-config.xml. I had it commented out before, not knowing that I needed it even if I won't use faces-config to define CustomerBean.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0">

  <application>
  <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
  </application>
</faces-config>
```